# How to add a page border with python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I want to add a page border to my MS Word Document using [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). How can I do ?

I check the [section](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Sections)'s documentation but I didn't find anything about this.

Comment: parcero did i answer your question? if not, is there something i can add to my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not supported by the official python-docx library, but you can implement it yourself. you're looking for [page borders](http://officeopenxml.com/WPsectionBorders.php) stored under [section properties](http://officeopenxml.com/WPsection.php).

Here's some code sample that should help you out:

```
import docx
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.shared import qn

doc = docx.Document()
sec_pr = doc.sections[0]._sectPr # get the section properties el
# create new borders el
pg_borders = OxmlElement('w:pgBorders')
# specifies how the relative positioning of the borders should be calculated
pg_borders.set(qn('w:offsetFrom'), 'page')
for border_name in ('top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right',): # set all borders
    border_el = OxmlElement(f'w:{border_name}')
    border_el.set(qn('w:val'), 'single') # a single line
    border_el.set(qn('w:sz'), '4') # for meaning of  remaining attrs please look docs
    border_el.set(qn('w:space'), '24')
    border_el.set(qn('w:color'), 'auto')
    pg_borders.append(border_el) # register single border to border el
sec_pr.append(pg_borders) # apply border changes to section

doc.save('border_test.docx')
```